# How is Xenodrome better than Xeno Sanctuary

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Xenodrome costs 750 production and 3 geothermal. It gives free Xeno Sanctuary and 4 culture.

While Xeno Sanctuary costs 330 production, 1 Xenomass and 1 energy. It gives 4 culture as well...

How is Xenodrome better than Xeno Sanctuary? Does it give and additional 4 culture? Is it worth more than 400 production?

Comment: If Xenodrome gives a free Xeno Sanctuary as well as 4 culture, then it gives all the benefits of a Xeno Sanctuary and also 4 culture. i.e. the total gain from Xenodrome is 1 Xenomass, 1 Energy, and 8 culture. Posting this as comment rather than answer because I don't have access to the game right now and can't verify - this is based on just reading the question...

Answer (score 2):

Well, off hand a big difference is that the Xenodrome is a wonder whereas the Xeno Sanctuary is a normal building.

So, as a wonder, you can only have one Xenodrome and only if no other Civ beats you to it. It gives a maintenance free Xeno Sanctuary when it's built, so it does in essence give you free culture.

The Sanctuary itself is a normal building, so you can have multiples, but they cost energy in maintenance.

That's the basic difference between the two. The Xenodrome is better because it's a wonder, but it has the downsides of wonders in that it's limited to one.

Comment: By the by, I didn't check in game but quickly on a wiki, but the Xenodrome costs 1500 production according to the wiki. It also costs no geothermal and gives +4/+4 to energy and science. I'll have to confirm when I get home and in the actual game, but that sounds more right for a wonder in a sorta bluish area of the Web and gives a free culture building anyways.